# about backpropagation deep neural network in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am reading about backpropagation deep neural network, and as I understood, I can summarize the  algorithm of that type of neural network as below :

**1- Input x** : Set the corresponding activation for the input layer

**2- Feedforward**: caclulate the error of the forward-propagation

**3- Output error:** Calculate the output error

**4- Backpropagate the error** : caclulate the error of the back-propagation

**5- Output:** Using the gradient of the cost function

That's ok, and then I check many codes of that type of deep network, below an example code with explanation :

```
### imports
import tensorflow as tf

### constant data
x  = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_ = [[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.]]

### induction
# 1x2 input -> 2x3 hidden sigmoid -> 3x1 sigmoid output

# Layer 0 = the x2 inputs
x0 = tf.constant( x  , dtype=tf.float32 )
y0 = tf.constant( y_ , dtype=tf.float32 )

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2,3] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
h1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0,m1 ) + b1 )

# Layer 2 = the 3x1 sigmoid output
m2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3,1] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [1]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
y_out = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) + b2 )


### loss
# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )

# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)


### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
  for step in range(500) :
    sess.run(train)

  results = sess.run([m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss])
  labels  = "m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss".split(",")
  for label,result in zip(*(labels,results)) :
    print ""
    print label
    print result

print ""
```

My question, the above code is calculating the error of the forward-propagation but I don't see any step for calculating the back-propagation error. In other words, following the above description, I can see the steps 1 (**Input x**) , 2 (**Feedforward**) , 3 (**Output error**) and 5 (**Output**) but the step number 4 which is (**Backpropagate the error**) is not shown in the code!!   Is that right or something missing in the code? The problem that all codes I found online are following same steps in backpropagation deep neural networks! 
please, could you describe how the step of **Backpropagate the error** is happening the code or what should I add something to performing that step?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, when you build the TF graph up to the point you are computing the loss in your code, TF will know on which `tf.Variable` (weights) the loss depends. Then, when you create the node `train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)`, and later run it in a `tf.Session`, the backpropagation is done for you in the background. To be more specific, the `train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)` merges the following steps:

```
# 1. Create a GD optimizer with a learning rate of 1.0
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0)
# 2. Compute the gradients for each of the variables (weights) with respect to the loss
gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
# 3. Update the variables (weights) based on the computed gradients
train = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
```

In particular, step `1` and `2`, summarize the backpropagation step. Hope that this makes things more clear for you!

---

Besides, I want to restructure the steps in your question:

1. **Input X:** The input of the neural network.
2. **Forward pass:** Propagating the input through the neural network, in order to get the output. In other words, multiplying the input X with each of the `tf.Variable` in your code.
3. **Loss**: The mismatch between the obtained output in step 2 and the expected output.
4. **Computing the gradients:** Computing the gradients for each of the `tf.Variable` (weights) with respect to the loss.
5. **Updating the weights**: Updating each `tf.Variable` (weight) according to its corresponding gradient.

Please note that step 4 and 5 encapsulate backpropagation.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. so what I understand now that backpropagation is not an independent neural network,  I mean all neural networks are performing backpropagation during the training phase, is that right ?

Comment: Basically that is what the training phase is. Computing the gradients of the weights with respect to the loss, and updating the weights of the neural network.

Comment: Yes I see .. you said "and updating the weights of the neural network" .. that update will be in forward-propagation and back-propagation ?  or only in forward-propagation  but  that (forward-propagation and back-propagation ) is only specific only for back-propagation neural networks ?

Comment: The forward pass (Forward propagation) is just multiplying the input with all of the matrices to get the output of the neural network. The loss, is the mismatch between the expected output and the output you got. Backpropagation is the the update of the weights with respect to the computed loss. Please don't get this the wrong way, but I really think that you should firstly learn these concepts before getting into TF. That way, you will have an easier time understanding everything and putting it into practice.

Comment: I also updated my answer based on your misconceptions. Feel free to check it out.